# Android APK installs but can't be found on device

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have built an app via Android Studio. The build is successful. I have created an APK file successfully. It is signed.

I have downloaded the APK to my device. It is found and unpacks successfully. I get the 'install anyway' prompt and it installs.

However, only the Done button is active, the Open button is disabled.

When I look for the app on my device icons (all screens not just home) it is not there. If I open Settings > Apps it is there.

What is going on? Surely if if is corrupt it wouldn't build or it would fail to launch but this is both installed and not installed at the same time.

Thanks.

EDIT: To be clear, in Settings > Apps I see the app and it says Installed but if I search for the app on my phone it is not found.

AndroidManifest as follows (this was built from new project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ts_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" />


</application>
```

Thanks everyone - I somehow lost my Launcher section of my Manifest. Working version below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application>
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ts_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:targetApi="31">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: If you have created the app, you can directly install it from android studio via USB cable connected from your machine to your device. This will give you logs and potential source of error.

Comment: Does it contain a launchable activity?

Comment: thanks - it is a simple webview so nothing within it should be an issue though there's always 6Mb of bloat with this that is hard to know if causing issues. Having issues with both emulator and usb device connection as well but will check on those if ever got them working

Comment: You still need launcher activity. Try to create new project from Android Studio new project wizard and look into Android Manifest to see how it should be configured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a launcher activity from where you are going to launch the webview.

Your manifest should contain something similar to this.

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.appName">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category           
                 android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Just to add explanation: The intent filter here is the key part necessary to make the app "openable" from the install window.

Comment: Thanks Tenfour04 - I've added current Manifest to question - maybe I edited this as from initial setup so will check tomorrow

Comment: lost my intent-filter section somehow - all working now - have added working code to question for ref - thanks

Answer (score 0):

An application intended to run on TV devices must declare a launcher activity for TV in its manifest. It uses a CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER intent filter to do this. This filter identifies your app as being enabled for TV and lets Google Play identify it as a TV app. When a user selects your app on their TV home screen, this intent identifies which activity to launch.

If you are building your app to run in TV devices as well, you should add the intent-filter to the activity:

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.android.TvActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">

<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If you don't include the CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER intent filter in your app, it's not visible to users running Google Play on TV devices. Also, if your app doesn't have this filter when you use developer tools to load it onto a TV device, the app does not appear in the TV user interface.

https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start